# Could you wish him a [get well soon] for me

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

I have a friend of a friend who is sick.

If I directly talked to the sick person I would say:

> I wish you would get well soon.

But I want the first friend to tell the second one.
So something along the lines:

> Could you wish him a ... for me?

If it was his birthday I could say:

> Could you wish him a **happy birthday** for me?

So how do you ask someone, to tell his friend that you wish him to get well soon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, This might help you.

> Could you wish him a **speedy recovery**?

A *"speedy recovery"* means that you hope that whoever it is you are talking about gets well soon. This can be used when you are not speaking to the subject himself.

Additionally, you could also say :

> Could you wish him a **quick recovery**?

Comment: It is not really necessary to use the preposition **from** in your sentences. Why do you think you need to use the preposition. Is there any better alternative?

Comment: Jeah, that works! I was to focused on using "get well".